# How to trigger a Model Observer in Laravel with the Maatwebsite/Excel package?

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

maybe is a problem with a simple solution, but i have a few hours trying to figure out.
Sorry for my bad english...

I have a project that manage Products, Clients, Orders, Currencies and other things, the most important thing here is the Product's operations with the database, i use Laravel 8 with Maatwebsite/excel package to manage imports of xlsx files with all the information about products.

The process of import the file is working perfectly, i have a ProductObserver file that triggers events only when i use the CRUD, the problem is that these events do not trigger when the import occurs.

I'll post all the files that i consider relevant for the process.

ProductObserver.php

```
     * Handle the Product "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Product  $product
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Product $product)
    {
      if ($product->check_custom_price != 'on') {

        $currencies = Currency::all();

        foreach ($currencies as $currency) {
          ProductPrice::create([
              'product_id'    => $product->id,
              'currency_id'   => $currency->id,
              'price'         => $product->base_price * $currency->value,
              'status'        => 'A'
          ]);
          }

      }
    }

    /**
     * Handle the Product "updated" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Product  $product
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(Product $product)
    {
      if($product->isDirty('base_price') && $product->check_custom_price != 'on'){
        ProductPrice::where('product_id', $product->id)->update([
          'status' => 'I',
        ]);

        $currencies = Currency::all();

        foreach ($currencies as $currency) {
          ProductPrice::create([
            'product_id'    => $product->id,
            'currency_id'   => $currency->id,
            'price'         => $product->base_price * $currency->value,
            'status'        => 'A'
        ]);
        }

      }
    }
```

The 2 events here triggers perfectly as i said.

ProductImport.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Product;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithUpserts;

class ProductsImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithUpserts
{

    /**
     * @return string|array
     */
    public function uniqueBy()
    {
        return 'name';
    }

    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Product([
          'name'                => $row['name'],
          'base_price'          => $row['base_price'],
          'check_custom_price'  => $row['check_custom_price'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

As you can see, i have `ProductPrice, Currency, Product` models with their tables to save every price the product have for every currency.

What am i missing?

UPDATE:
EventServiceProviders.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Currency;

use App\Observers\ProductObserver;
use App\Observers\CurrencyObserver;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Product::observe(new ProductObserver);
        Currency::observe(new CurrencyObserver);
    }
}
```

The Observer is registered, i don't have any problems with that, when i create or update a product using the controller actions it works like charm, thanks for the answer.

I'm pretty sure the problem is the way the package save the model.

in this docs: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/model.html, they say:
"The returned model will be saved for you. Each row will result into (at least) one save and will also fire model events."

And the `save` event triggers the same as create or update.

But when imports... nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that when importing the data it is using ->insert() method which does prevent firing any event.

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/2220

Comment: Following you link i found some other methods to make the Importing process triggers the observer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong in the code so I think maybe you forgot to register the observer.

```php
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Observers\ProductObserver;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Product::observe(ProductObserver::class);
    }    
}
```